# How do I modify an IntNode?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

Java Jackson question here:

I'm trying to edit a JsonNode created by objectMapper.readTree,

```
jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);
```

, but it automatically turned some of the branches of the node into IntNodes.  If it were a string, I could easily edit the value like so:

```
((ObjectNode)jsonNode).put("name","newvalue");
```

But if it's a number,

```
 ((IntNode)jsonNode).put("number",42);
```

Will fail because 'put' is not a method of IntNode.

How do I modify an IntNode?

Comment: You can't.  you need to create a new IntNode and replace it.

Comment: You need to give more context around this single line of code,
so that people can better advise how to solve your issue.

Comment: @OldProgrammer that did it.  Thank you.  If you write an answer I will mark it as correct.